# Chi square statistics (chen & thissen, 1997) for local dependence testing in IRT models

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, item-response-theory

I have recently computed the test for local dependence based on X2 statistics ([Chen & Thissen, 1997](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1165285)) in RStudio with the mirt package like this:
residuals(fit.SKIDDETdisc,
type = "LD",
df.p=TRUE
)

This is the output I am getting:
Degrees of freedom (lower triangle) and p-values:

```
       SKID_1 SKID_2 SKID_33 SKID_59 SKID_61 SKID_63 SKID_65 SKID_98
    SKID_1      NA      0   0.001       0   0.026   0.010   0.037   0.001
    SKID_2       1     NA   0.000       0   0.001   0.043   0.036   0.002
    SKID_33      1      1      NA       0   0.043   0.000   0.000   0.000
    SKID_59      1      1   1.000      NA   0.004   0.001   0.050   0.000
    SKID_61      1      1   1.000       1      NA   0.044   0.062   0.048
    SKID_63      1      1   1.000       1   1.000      NA   0.000   0.000
    SKID_65      1      1   1.000       1   1.000   1.000      NA   0.000
    SKID_98      1      1   1.000       1   1.000   1.000   1.000      NA

    LD matrix (lower triangle) and standardized values:

     SKID_1 SKID_2 SKID_33 SKID_59 SKID_61 SKID_63 SKID_65 SKID_98
   SKID_1      NA  0.168   0.091   0.187   0.064   0.074  -0.059   0.092
   SKID_2  34.724     NA   0.111   0.207   0.093   0.058   0.060   0.087
   SKID_33 10.122 15.101      NA   0.201  -0.058   0.267   0.162   0.351
   SKID_59 42.974 52.620  49.480      NA   0.081   0.098   0.056   0.211
   SKID_61  4.966 10.598   4.106   8.115      NA   0.057  -0.053   0.056
   SKID_63  6.673  4.104  87.607  11.858   4.038      NA   0.142   0.233
   SKID_65  4.340  4.375  32.059   3.849   3.475  24.732      NA   0.146
   SKID_98 10.334  9.328 151.424  54.621   3.909  66.590  26.060      NA
   > residuals(fit.SKIDDETdisc,
    #For the 'LD' and 'LDG2' types, the upper diagonal elements represent the 
    standardized residuals in the form of signed Cramers V coefficients
```

but I can't find how this test is interpreted and if there are any cut-offs which indicate, that local depencdence between items is occuring?

Is anyone here familiar with IRT models and their assumptions and has tested them in RStudio with the mirt package?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, as a psychometrician (in training) who primarily uses IRT models, I can say that I never adhere to cutoffs$^1$ when applying IRT models. Part of this has to do with the goal of most IRT analyses, which is to develop an item bank for scoring or later use. This sentiment is best summarized by Chen & Thissen (1997) -

> The LD indexes are intended to be used not for hypothesis testing but for diagnostic purposes. Any meaningful interpretation of the LD indexes requires skill and experience in IRT analysis and close examination of the item content. Examination of the pattern of the LD indexes across item pairs is as important as the magnitude of any single LD index.

So while measures of LD, such as the $\chi^2$ LD index, are helpful, they are not to be used to formally include or exclude items unless paired with an examination of the item content. Additionally, measures of LD should be evaluated using other information from your model, such as reliability and measures of overall (or "global") fit (e.g., the RMSEA$_2$, SRMSR, & TLIRT)$^2$.

This being said, there does appear to be a non-negligible amount of LD. For instance, Chen & Thissen (1997) used 3.84 and 6.63 as (potential) cutpoints to evaluate their $\chi^2$ LD metric, and over 1/3 of your item pairs look to exceed 13. Given this, I would advise you to review the item content (of these item pairs in particular) in conjunction with the goals of your analysis.

$^1$ See McNeish & Wolf (2023) for a good discussion about issues related to cutoffs.

$^2$ See Maydeu-Olivares & Joe (2014) for more information regarding the RMSEA$_2$ and SRMSR, and see Cai, Chung, & Lee (2023) for more information regarding the TLIRT (which is the IRT version of the TLI). Also, see Maydeu-Olivares (2013) and Maydeu-Olivares (2014) for good general discussions of IRT model fit.

**References**

Cai, L., Chung, S. W., & Lee, T. (2023). Incremental model fit assessment in the case of categorical data: Tucker–lewis index for item response theory modeling. Prevention Science, 24(3), 455-466.

Chen, W. H., & Thissen, D. (1997). Local dependence indexes for item pairs using item response theory. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 22(3), 265-289.

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2013). Goodness-of-fit assessment of item response theory models. Measurement: Interdisciplinary Research and Perspectives, 11(3), 71-101.

Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2014). Evaluating the fit of IRT models. In Handbook of item response theory modeling (pp. 111-127). Routledge.

Maydeu-Olivares, A., & Joe, H. (2014). Assessing approximate fit in categorical data analysis. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 49(4), 305-328.

McNeish, D., & Wolf, M. G. (2023). Dynamic fit index cutoffs for confirmatory factor analysis models. Psychological Methods, 28(1), 61.